# How to redirect sub.Domain.com to a folder (Domain.com/folder, etc.) in IIS7?

Tags: rewrite, iis-7.5

How can I redirect a subdomain to a folder using IIS7.5 remotely managing our website?

So:

sub.MyDomain.com would resolve to MyDomain.com/folder

I've tried using URL Rewrite but it's not seeming to have any effect.
I didn't read anything about there needing to be DNS propagation (seems like that's not necessary).

Do I perhaps need to somehow set the DNS records know that IIS is handling that subdomain?

FYI, here are the settings I used:

If the Pattern is for a subdomain that I've created a CNAME DNS record for (pointing to the main domain: www.BungalowSoftware.com) then I get a 403 Forbidden result (so its hitting the server @ web.com)
If the subdomain does NOT exist in the DNS (CNAME) then I get "not found".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the site in IIS. aka sub.mydomain.com, after in it you simply do a 301 redirect to the relative path in your other folder.

A bit like told [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082219/redirect-subdomain-url-to-another-subdomain-in-iis)

The setting I mean is there, when you click your added subdomain:

[image]

Comment: IIS on my PC is remotely managing a site hosted by web.com. So would I still create this additional site, on my own PC's IIS?

Comment: IIS on my PC is giving me options (in upper left drop down) to CONNECT (not *create*) to a Site |Server|Application.

Comment: @ClayNichols You need to create another website under IIS with the subdomain you have, and create a 301 redirect to the folder. Do you have admin right to do so on the hoster ?

Comment: @ClayNichols Updated my answer, and FYI, the subdomain in IIS will allow IIS to manage the Host HEADER to the correct site binding, while if no site is added, IIS got no idea what header it's for.